# Rich enumeration in Scala

Tags: scala, enumeration

I am looking for a mechanism to implement rich enumerations in Scala, the same way you can in Java add abstract methods to enums and implement them in the instances of of the enum.

Please note that using a sealed trait and case objects is not a solution, because I would not be able to iterate over the existing case objects, unless I mantain a list of them, which is very fragile to changes (especially by other people who don't understand what's going on there)

Comment: >"unless I mantain a list of them" Can't it be generated by a macro?

Comment: Maybe, but I have no experience with macros. I would have to inspect all the subclasses of my trait which are case objects... any hint?

Comment: Unfortunately, me too. But it will be interesting to see a solution.
Also, you can try to construct the list at runtime with reflection, it will be only small penalty, because it is done once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just extend `Val`.

```
object items extends Enumeration {

  val pen = Item("writing")
  val brush = Item("painting")

  final case class Item(key: String) extends Val {
    def kind: String = toString
  }
}

object Test {
  import items._
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(pen.kind +" is for "+ pen.key)
    println(brush.key)
    println(items.values)
  }
}
```

or

```
object days extends Enumeration {
  case class Day(i: Int, name: String) extends Val(i, name) {
    def isWeekDay = i < 5
  }
  private def newDay() = new Day(nextId, null)
  val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = newDay()
  val daysOfTheWeek = values.toList.asInstanceOf[List[Day]]
}

object Test extends App {
  import days._
  println(Thu)
  println(days.values.toList mkString ",")
  for (d <- days.daysOfTheWeek) Console println s"$d is weekday? ${d.isWeekDay}"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Check also what Viktor Klang suggested here: https://gist.github.com/viktorklang/1057513

It's a very safe way to construct an enum.

Comment: I have just tried to use Klang's code at this URL. I cannot get it to work. I continue to receive "warning: match is not exhaustive!". Did something in the Scala compiler change between the version he was using (mid 2011) and now (mid 2014)?